# Why I am getting an empty array while fatcing data using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, axios

I am learning react js and redux. I am trying to fetch some images from jsonplaceholder. Their image api is "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos". No error is showing on the browser console. But there is no data. I can't find why the data is not fetching.

Here is my code.

**imageSlice.js**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  images: [],
  error: null,
  isLoading: false,
};

export const fetchImages = createAsyncThunk('images/fetchImages', async () => {
  const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  return res.data;
});

export const imageSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'images',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchImages.pending, state => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchImages.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.images = action.payload;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchImages.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.images = [];
      state.error = action.error.message;
    });
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {} = imageSlice.actions;

export default imageSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import imageReducer from './imageSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    images: imageReducer,
  },
});
```

**Images.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchImages } from '../redux/imageSlice';

const Images = () => {
  const { images } = useSelector(state => state.images);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchImages());
  }, []);
  console.log(images);

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h2>Images</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;
```

On the **Images.jsx** file, in **line no 9**, I am fetching data from jsonplaceholder. But not getting any data?

**Here is image of console**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPzkN.png)

Where is my fault? How to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you run into the error case? Have you debugged what `action.payload` looks like in the success case?